# How can I show/hide a navbar with jquery on a specific width?

Tags: jquery, scroll, width, show, nav

I know the following code is wrong. I just need to know how to show a navbar on scroll and width at the same time. So I wrote it like that for better understanding:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300 ) && if ($(window).width() > 768 ) {

    $('#scroll-nav').slideDown(300);

} else {

    $('#scroll-nav').slideUp(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can this:

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300 && $(window).width() > 768 ) {

        $('#scroll-nav').slideDown(300);

    } else {

        $('#scroll-nav').slideUp(300);
    }
```